# R coding with functions nan and na

Tags: r

How would I be able to write a function with one argument that inputs an object and outputs `TRUE` only if the corresponding elements are `NA` (it should return `FALSE` for `NaN`) with the vector `c(7,NA,4,NA,3,Inf,NaN)`.

Comment: `is.na(x) & !is.nan(x)`

Answer (score 1):

```
bar <- c(7,NA,4,NA,3,Inf,NaN)
bar
#> [1]   7  NA   4  NA   3 Inf NaN
foo <- function(x) is.na(x) & !is.nan(x)
foo(bar)
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```